# Graph Embeddings with Weka

Tags: graph, embedding

I want to use weka with graphs containing nodes and edges. Is it possible to generate graph embeddings and classify them in Weka?

Answer (score 0):

Weka doesn't handle graphs natively, you would need to convert the data into a tabular format beforehand (even its support for relational attributes won't be sufficient to represent graphs, I believe). At the time of writing, I'm not aware of any Weka package that could load/preprocess graphs in some fashion.